# Firefox minimal build

Tags: firefox

I want to compile a portable version of Firefox 3 on a low cost Intel Celeron Windows Xp machine to run as a kiosk computer. So i just want the browsing functionality since i'll be running it on the fullscreen mode. What are the steps to do a minimal rebuild from the sources?
Also what is firefox's command line parameters to open a site from the cmd?

Comment: Would the Prism FF extension be better for this kind of functionality?

Comment: What about building a portable FF build? what are the steps to do it?

Comment: Seriously? 14 questions and 0 accepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Stripped down minimal build" doesn't really make any sense. You can't really exclude any functionality that would make it run faster or be any smaller, since most of the code that Firefox needs to render webpages is the same code that it uses to render its user interface. Forget about trying to "strip down" the code.

That being said, it sounds like you probably want to use [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner), which will let you use all the web browsing functionality of Firefox, but wrap it in your own GUI. You can find an ultra-minimalist browser XUL application here:

http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/xulrunner/mybrowser-0.2.2.xulapp

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Kiosk mode addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1659) (more for a lock-down) for Firefox.

You may be in general interested in this other question here:
[How to lock down Windows XP for use as an internet kiosk](https://serverfault.com/questions/18879/how-to-lock-down-windows-xp-for-use-as-an-internet-kiosk)?

Here is a gHacks reference for [custom builds](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/05/09/firefox-custom-builds/).
<sup>and, a [Prism reference](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/05/09/mozilla-prism-10-beta/).</sup>

Comment: I won't prefer the Windows SteadyState solution for Kiosk mode action. I would want to run a stripped down optimized version of FF on the Celeron machine.

Comment: @iceman, hope you looked at the other links besides the steady state one.

Answer (score 0):

http://webconverger.com/ provides a minimalistic OS build featuring Firefox. There is also [build instructions](http://webconverger.org/develop/) if you want to build your own customised images.